# Function should accept any container, but return a list of the type inside the container

Tags: c++, sfinae

I created a function which requires a function of list of function pointer as seen in `function_creater` and returns a function of lists.

I am trying to remove the `std::list<>` as a part of the input parameters, where should accept any arbitrary container e.g.

`funciton_creater(std::function<some_container<std::function<void(T&)>>(T&)> trans_func)`

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::function<std::list<T>(T&)> funciton_creater(std::function<std::list<std::function<void(T&)>>(T&)> trans_func){
    return [trans_func](T& state) {
        auto transitions = trans_func(state);
        std::list<T> new_states{};
        for (auto&& trans : transitions) {
            auto succ = state;
            trans(succ);
            new_states.push_back(succ);
        };
        return new_states;
    };
}
```

As for this construction I have been trying to use Sfinae where I currently have:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void> // primary declaration
struct is_container : std::false_type {}; // when all specializations fail

template <typename T>
struct is_container< // specialization  
    T, // conditions:
    std::void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>
> : std::true_type
{};
template <typename C>  // *_v value
constexpr auto is_container_v = is_container<C>::value;
```

My problem is that I am unable to construct an `std::enable_if` statement which checks if the `std::function` contains a container.

Comment: I cannot see neither pointers nor lists of functions here.

Comment: Why exactly you need SFINAE in the first place? Is there some fallback solution? Better error message?